# Поймать файл расширения для chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

У меня есть установленное расширение для chrome (чужое, установленное из chrome web store). Мне надо достать .crx файл этого расширения. Как проще всего это сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to download Chrome extensions for installing in another computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/290280/)

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё сам нашёл:
linux - home/%username%/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions

Answer (score 0):

Вот для Windows: C:/Documents and Settings/<USERNAME>/Local Settings/Application Data/Google/Chrome/User Data/Extensions. Но файла .crx там нет. Поэтому лучше на зайти в Chrome Web Store, там найти приложение и установить.